# lumen framework View not working

Tags: php, laravel, view, lumen

I use the Lumen framework for first time,  the View does not work
This is my code

```
return view('user');
```

But I get the following error:

> InvalidArgumentException in FileViewFinder.php line 140:
>   View [user] not found.

But I use the following code is possible

```
return view()->file('..\resources\views\user.blade.php');
```

What could the problem be?

Comment: You do not need to specify the full path. Are you sure the file exists?

Comment: Yes，This file exists

Comment: Is your `resources` folder in the root directory? (not `app/resources`)

Comment: @lukasgeiter, mine is in the root and having the same issue. I think this is a bug with the current version (the code worked before, when sqlite didn't...).

Comment: @balintant Sorry I can't reproduce the issue with a fresh installation.

Comment: @lukasgeiter: Lumen is a fresh system, there must be some kind of major change, which crashes our applications after `composer update`. Will be fixed soon, I think.

Comment: Please is there a solution to this, as i still always encounter the error view not found.. please help

Answer (score 1):

The problem came with an update of Lumen. I don't know what has changed but more people met the issue when upgrading from an older version of theframework.

I think this issue will not be relevant anytime soon, so the answer is "we don't have an answer" and it does not worth to find it out by now.

Comment: I found this also to be true. I upgraded to a newer version of lumen and no longer had the odd view problem that led me here.

Answer (score 0):

Change permissions of 'storage/framework/views' folder. It should be writable for web server.

Comment: I have the same problem, but if I try to specify the file just like he said, I get the "PermissionDenied" exception. (Btw, I serve Lumen via `artisan serve`, so I am not expected to get permission issues...)

Comment: `storage/framework/views/*` only needs `+r` permission.